# Is my WKT projection definition wrong or is there a bug in PROJ?

Tags: coordinate-system, proj, well-known-text

I'm using PROJ with a WKT projection string to try and match a coordinate system being employed in a 3rd party solution.

I seem to be able to match the 3rd party coordinates when projecting EPSG:3857 coordinates to my WKT definition, but when I try to convert back again the Y value is correct but the X values is completely wrong.

I'm pretty new trying to use WKT projection strings so I'm wondering if there's something wrong with my definition?

This is my custom WKT definition:

```
PROJCS["PacificIslands",
    GEOGCS["NZGD2000",
        DATUM["New_Zealand_Geodetic_Datum_2000",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6167"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4167"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",-21.2],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-159.75],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","100001"]]
```

If I take the following EPSG:3857 coordinates:

```
X: 22295668.360
Y: -2414760.379
```

Projecting them using the WKT given above:

```
X: 3674.005
Y: 909.963
```

Then if I project them back to EPSG:3857 again I get:

```
X: -17779348.325
Y: -2414760.379
```

Any idea what's going on?

I've tried this in both the C++ PROJ 8.0.0 library and using the C# ProjNet library and get the same result.

Here's my C++ PROJ example code in case it's of any use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <proj.h>

int main(void) {
    PJ_CONTEXT* C;
    PJ* P;

    /* or you may set C=PJ_DEFAULT_CTX if you are sure you will     */
    /* use PJ objects from only one thread                          */
    C = proj_context_create();

    P = proj_create_crs_to_crs(C,
        "EPSG:3857",
        "PROJCS[\"PacificIslands\",GEOGCS[\"NZGD2000\",DATUM[\"New_Zealand_Geodetic_Datum_2000\",SPHEROID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7019\"]],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6167\"]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],UNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4167\"]],PROJECTION[\"Transverse_Mercator\"],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",-21.2],PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",-159.75],PARAMETER[\"scale_factor\",0.9996],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",0],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",0],UNIT[\"metre\",1,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9001\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"100001\"]]",
        NULL);

    PJ_COORD coordFrom, coordTo, coordReversed;
    coordFrom = proj_coord(22295668.3602, -2414760.3791, 0, 0);

    coordTo = proj_trans(P, PJ_FWD, coordFrom);
    printf("ORIGINAL x: %.3f, y: %.3f\n", coordFrom.enu.e, coordFrom.enu.n);
    printf("CONVERTED x: %.3f, y: %.3f\n", coordTo.enu.e, coordTo.enu.n);

    // Reverse again
    coordReversed = proj_trans(P, PJ_INV, coordTo);
    printf("REVERSED BACK x: %.3f, y: %.3f\n", coordReversed.enu.e, coordReversed.enu.n);

    /* Clean up */
    proj_destroy(P);
    proj_context_destroy(C); /* may be omitted in the single threaded case */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like your original EPSG:3857 coordinates are outside the usual bounds of `[-20037508.3428, 20037508.3428]` meters (-180 to +180 degrees), as though they wrapped around the antemeridian. In fact, when we calculate `22295668.360 - (2 * 20037508.3428)`, we get -17779348.3256, the same as the output value. The difference  between the two equals the circumference of the Earth (40075016.6856 meters).

Comment: @FSimardGIS thank you for that, that was the issue! I had sourced my coordinates from http://bboxfinder.com/ but it provides incorrect coordinates if you scroll past the 180th meridian before selecting your area. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me with gdaltransform when using valid EPSG:3857 coordinates as @FSimardGIS noticed. I had to remove the last line with a fake EPSG code from your WKT but after that:

```
gdaltransform -t_srs proj.prj -s_srs epsg:3857
Enter X Y [Z [T]] values separated by space, and press Return.
19333064.690113 -5216915.262195
-2193080.84767025 -2703101.3572082 0

>gdaltransform -s_srs proj.prj -t_srs epsg:3857
Enter X Y [Z [T]] values separated by space, and press Return.
-2193080.84767025 -2703101.3572082 0
19333064.690113 -5216915.262195 0
```